# Hide text when nested arrays are missing/non-existent

Tags: javascript

I have some MUI cards which are mapped based on an API response.  The API response generally looks like this:

```
{
  "displaygroups": {
    "ConslutingQuestions": [],
    "IntakeQuestions": [],
    "IntakeValidations": [],
    "SoftwareQuestions": []
  }
}
```

Sometimes, only one or two of the nested arrays are present in the API response, and sometimes `displayGroups` is empty.  I have some hardcoded helper text describing the purpose of each of these nested arrays.  I want to hide some of this text when some of the arrays are missing and I want to hide all of the text when `displayGroups` is empty.

When `displayGroups` is empty, it looks like this: `{"displaygroups": []}`

`questionGroups` is where I store the API response.

When I load a document where `IntakeValidations` is populated, this `if` block runs through the first check and logs `IntakeValidations` as undefined, even though there is data being displayed on screen.

```
if (typeof questionGroups.displayGroups?.IntakeValidations === "undefined") {
    console.log("array is undefined");
    setValidationsHidden(true);
} else if (typeof questionGroups.displayGroups?.IntakeValidations !== "undefined") {
    console.log("is not undefined");
    setValidationsHidden(false);
}
```

This `if` block results in the same outcome:

```
if (!questionGroups.displayGroups?.IntakeValidations) {
    console.log("There is no IntakeValidations");
    setValidationsHidden(true);
} else setValidationsHidden(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this statement will never change:

"When displayGroups is empty, it looks like this: `{"displaygroups": []}` "

So basically you can check if `displayGroups` is an instance of an Array or an Object.

You can check it by doing the following ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray?retiredLocale=tr)):

```
Array.isArray(displayGroups)
```

and then if it is not an array you can loop through the keys of the `displayGroups` by doing the following:

```
Object.keys(displayGroups).forEach(key => {
// hide/show stuff
})
```

Comment: `console.log(Array.isArray(questionGroups.displayGroups));` returns `false`.  Is this correct?  Then if it is false, I use `Object.keys(questionGroups?.displayGroups).forEach((key) => { console.log(key); });`, but I get the error message `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: I recommend you to log "questionGroups" and check if it has "displayGroups" then if displayGroups is not an array it means it is an object in your case.

Comment: `displayGroups` is an object when it is populated as shown in the question.  In my first example of my API response, that is what is in `questionGroups`, and is set like this: `setQuestionGroups(API_RESPONSE)`.

Comment: okay but you're passing 'null' or undefined' to Object.keys() method as a parameter so please log questionGroups.displayGroups if it's existing

Comment: logging `questionGroups.displayGroups` returns undefined.  But I can still map into it and its subsequent arrays to display data on my cards.

Comment: When I log `questionGroups`, I get the exact response I have in my question: ```{"displaygroups": { "IntakeQuestions": [], "IntakeValidations": [] } }```  The arrays IntakeQuestions and IntakeValidations are both filled with objects.

Comment: ok then, 
1. `Array.isArray(questionGroups.displayGroups) ` should return false
2. `Object.keys(questionGroups.displayGroups)` should not throw any errors, instead it should return an array like ` [
    "IntakeQuestions",
    "IntakeValidations"
]` and then you'll be able to loop through this array to show or hide fields you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247446/discussion-between-ciaran-crowley-and-minikdev).